# Can't resume first activity after rotate in second activity

Tags: android, android-intent

i searched here for a while a can't find anything usefull about my problem. i'm writing something like Gallery, i have photos, then when i click on one of them, i use intent to create new activity where i'm using ratingbar to rate picture, and after all i press back button and again using intent i'm sending rating result to my frist activity. Everything works fine but i found out that this sequence

- open app
- click image
- open second activity by intent
- rotate screen
- click back

is not working at all, of course if i do all this steps in landscape or portrait without rotate it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a dumb idea, but did you try to set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` for your activity ? Maybe both of your activities ? Perhaps it's because they get reloaded on orientation change that freaks your app logic up.